# How to check if a command is hanged in a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script, in which I call another script and sometimes second script hangs. Is there any way to check if it is hung or not. And I can't make any changes is the second script.

```
#!/bin/bash
calling second script(thata might hang)

if hang then do something
```

Answer (score 3):

If you already know a threshold time, that after that script is considered hung. you can use `timeout`.

```
timeout 30 bash script.sh
```

command `bash script.sh` will run until it finish in less that 30 seconds or gets killed by timeout. You can adjust the time according to your environment.

Command Reference:

```
timeout
Usage: timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
  or:  timeout [OPTION]
Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after DURATION.
```

Please refer to respective `man page` for `options`.